Android Jitpack release and debug build
I'm new to Jitpack and Android library releases.
What I try to achieve is having a Jitpack release, which includes debug and release artifact of the library I created. For more details look at my Jitpack-Issue.
Is there a way to just swap in Android Studio between debug and release build and it automatically swaps that for the dependency too? or what is the proper way to support a "debugMode" where the integrator of the library see logs and stuff like that?
I'll have the case, that integrators wont be able to have the library code available to just push themself to mavenLocal or integrate it as a submodule.
I hope it is just some Android Gradle publishing config I'm doing wrong, but it seems there is not much docs around for Android + Jitpack + Gradle 8.x that is up to date (or at least i didn't find that much)
I've created a demoProject for this. So my expectation would be like that both artifacts (debug and release) will be included and published on Jitpack and can be used with the same dependency.
But it always only uses the releaseArtifact:
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final String LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.custom.testlibrary";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";

    public BuildConfig() {
    }
}

Version 0.0.8 can be used to check that behavior
Much appreciate any help!
